# Is there a way to stagger TestNG tests by a set amount of time? If so, how?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I'm running Selenium tests written in Java with TestNG. I would like to run tests in my suite concurrently, but I don't want them to start at the same time.  The environment that I'm running them against can't handle it.  Ideally, I'd like one to start every 30 seconds.  Is there a way to do this? If so, how?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the actual problem here. You want to run tests in parallel, but environment can't handle that. If so, why do you still want to run them in parallel? Perhaps you just want to decrease thread-count in testng.xml?

What you are looking for is called ramp up time in performance testing world, and TestNG doesn't implement such feature. Threads are created at initialization time. I think for some reason you are overcomplicating simple thing. If env can't handle all tests running in parallel n threads if they start at the same time, just lower thread count and then let them run.

Answer (score 1):

Well, no direct way.  What you can do is, in [IInvokedMethodListener](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IInvokedMethodListener.html) in beforeInvocation method, you can add a wait time before each test method runs. 
This would make every test start with a bit of delay.

Make the time configurable ofcourse - 30 seconds is a lot for each method to start.

Answer (score 0):

TestNG doesn't provide such kind of feature.

But you can have your own code which will manage the execution of many testng instances.